# ClassNotFoundException when trying to start topology

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

This is a strange problem that I'm hoping someone's encountered and overcome.

I have a relatively simple topology:

```
Spout -> BoltA -> BoltB
      -> BoltC
```

If I use bolts A and B, it works. A and C works too. Enabling all three though gives me this:

```
16:05:20.627 [main] WARN  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Topology submission exception. (topology name='traffic') #<RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$normalize_conf$get_merged_conf_val__3916$fn__3917>
16:05:20.634 [main] ERROR o.a.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$normalize_conf$get_merged_conf_val__3916$fn__3917
at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:88) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$read_storm_conf.invoke(nimbus.clj:89) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$start_storm.invoke(nimbus.clj:724) ~[storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar:0.9.1-incubating]
at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$eval3974$exec_fn__1459__auto__$reify__3987.submitTopologyWithOpts(nimbus.clj:962) ~[na:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$eval3974$exec_fn__1459__auto__$reify__3987.submitTopology(nimbus.clj:971) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
```

I'm running it locally using the code below:

```
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology(topoName, conf, buildTopology(source, service));
try {
  Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
cluster.killTopology(topoName);
cluster.shutdown();
```

I'm running against `storm-core-0.9.1-incubating.jar`

All I could find was [this discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@storm.incubator.apache.org/msg01907.html) about it "being a classpath issue". The fact that it only happens after adding a third bolt, but it doesn't matter which bolt, really confuses me. Is there something that Storm does once it has a "sufficiently complex topology" that kicks in at 3 bolts or 4 components?

#### EDIT

Well, it gets weirder. After finding [someone with the same problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/storm-user/classnotfoundexception/storm-user/yOtE3Em50bA/tRP9CpMUNP0J) I tried their solution and added to my logback.xml:

```
<logger name="backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus" level="INFO" />
```

which fixed the problem. Anything higher (WARN, ERROR) brings it back. Lower (DEBUG) is fine. Removing this line and setting the root logger to DEBUG brings the problem back, so I'm really confused. If something in the code path depends on `logger.isInfoEnabled()` shouldn't it act the same for `rootLogger=INFO` and `backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus=INFO`?

Comment: I don't know if it is the root of the problem but the highest logback version you can use is 0.9.17 for storm 0.8.x. If you try using latest versions of logback you'll get troubles (for instance: 1.0.13) in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using storm 0.9.1, and the logback I'm using (1.0.6) is coming directly from `org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.9.1-incubating`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had the same problem and editing logback.xml helped!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but did you try increasing the wait time before killing the topology?  10 seconds isn't really that much time for Storm to be able to come up completely and it's possible on teardown it's throwing away environment stuff that it thinks aren't needed anymore

Comment: Absolutely agree with Chris comment need to increase wait time. try for 2 min